# jq: retrieve values from multiple entries

Tags: json, curl, jq

(I have searched, but found nothing.)

I have a (huge) json file I got from Jira, and I want to get from it several values from different entries, using curl via linux.

For example:

```
{
   "expand": "names, schema",
   "startAt":0,
   "maxResults":1,
   "total":46,
   "issues":[
      {
         "key":"ABCD-12345",
         "fields":{
            "updated":"2020-12-03T13:16:17.000+0200",
            "customfield_18484":null,
            "customfield_14687":null,
            "customfield_14688":null,
            "customfield_18800":null,
            "customfield_23380":"",
            "customfield_18480":"off"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And I want to get the key (ABCD-12345) and the updated (2020-12-03T13:16:17.000+0200).

Each command works separately, but I can't figure out how to combine them.

My commands:

```
curl -s -g -H "Content-Type: application/json" "<link to my jira with search parameters" -u "<user>:<password>" | jq '.issues[].key' | tr -d '"'
```

returns ABCD-12345

```
curl -s -g -H "Content-Type: application/json" "<link to my jira with search parameters" -u "<user>:<password>" | jq  '.issues[].fields | "\(.updated)"' | tr -d '"'
```

returns 2020-12-06T10:08:06.000+0200

I have tried several combinations, like:
jq '.issues[].fields | "(.updated)"' | jq '.issues[].key'
jq '.issues[].fields | "(.updated)", .issues[].key'

But they didn't work.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you want the jq output to look like? (Oh, and read up on its `-r` option).

Answer (score 1):

This should achieve what you wanted :

```
jq -r '.issues[] | .key+" "+.fields.updated'
```